# call fo a file from PHP

Tags: php

i writing a PHP script that call a file in the server
by using :

```
<?php
$ret=system("command");
?>
```

the problem is when the file need some parameters
i can't find a way of doing that

because when using

```
<?php
$ret=system("command");
?>
```

the PHP skips that part of asking for variables 
and assign to id a random one

and i can't pass theme  at the start  like

```
$ret = system("command argument1 argument2 argument3...");
```

beause the nmber of parametres depend on the user
i mean he keep  entring data to a dynamic array entill he enter"end"

Comment: "PHP skips the part of asking for variables" - could you elaborate on this?

Comment: what is the command? I think that may be an issue here.

Comment: Are you wanting to pipe data into the program's [`STDIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)? If so it's probably [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) you're looking for...

Comment: every edit you make, obscures the question more.

Comment: ok thank you all i think i'll use proc_open()  and sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1):

```
$ret = system("command argument1 argument2 argument3...");
```

Just load the arguments on, just like you were calling the program from a command line.

Comment: no i can't do that because the number of parametres depends on the tm of the execution i have a loop and the user keep enring data until he enter "end"

Comment: Don't forget to [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)... ;-)

Comment: Then use `implode(array_map("escapeshellarg",$input));`, where `$input` is the array your user entered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cmd = "cmd param1 param2";
system($cmd,$return_value);
($return_value == 0) or die("returned an error: $cmd");
```

Comment: and i can't pass theme at the start like beause the nmber of parametres depend on the user i mean he keep entring data to a dynamic array entill he enter"end"

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is that you have an array that can have any number of parameters use this:

```
$commandParameters = implode(" ",$dynamicArray);
$ret = system("command ".escapeshellarg($commandParameters));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the parameters from the user via. HTML form and then, when you know what (and how many) the parameters are - you can use "system()" like everyone suggested!